# Adding Veritcal Scrollbar to Horizontally aligned parent panel

Tags: javascript, css, gwt

A panel with horizontal alignment is containing two child panels. The height of one of them changes dynamically. I want to add vertical scrollbar on the parent panel when this child panel overflows. If I am using default layout for the parent panel which is vertical. It is working. But in case of horizontal alignment, it is not. Can anyone please help? I am using GWT.

Comment: What panel? What child panel? There is a major difference bewteen widgets.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this is a **Java** question?? It sure smells Javascript to me, and if I'm right, then you are not getting the right experts to your question due to your mis-tag.

Comment: Changed the tags. Yes, the dynamic child panel overflows, I want vertical scrollbar in the parent panel.